# How to run any program with batch file from any specific location

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch file for open a specific program but it is not working.I wrote this :

```
@echo off
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K "cd /d C:\Program Files (x86)\HTC\HTC Sync Manager\"
start HTCSyncManager.exe
```

[image]

> When I run the batch file only this window come, program do not start. How to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

For /r c: %%f in (path goes here /HTCsyncmanager.exe) do (

start "%%f"

"%%f"

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the invoking of `cmd.exe`. All that's doing is starting a new instance of the command processor, which is not what you need at all. (You probably don't need the `start`, either.)

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\HTC\HTC Sync Manager\"
HTCSyncManager.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

start "HTCSyncManager" "C:\Program Files\(x86)\HTC\HTC Sync Manager\HTCSyncManager.exe"
```

This will open HTCSyncManager.